# Same table relation sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

so I've got a table like this:

```
ID | article | comment | content
```

so the article column is relative to another table called articles and comment is relative to the ID of current table, but what I want to do is get all comments to the current article and also to the comments in 1 query, is it possible?

Here's sample data

[image]

It should return the first 2 rows because they have `article = 33`, and the last row because it has `comment = 2`, which is the `id` of one of the `article = 33` rows.

I've tried something like this before if it may help to understand my question

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article=:article OR comment=comments.id
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: mysql @N00bPr0grammer

Comment: SELECT * FROM comments INNER JOIN articles ON comments.article = articles.id WHERE comments.article = articleid

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM comments
WHERE article IN (select * from comments where comment=comments.id);

Answer (score 0):

You can do an INNER JOIN and get all the results at one place as per the query provided earlier.

Query-1:

```
SELECT comments.* FROM comments 
WHERE comments.article = 'article_id'
```

Query-2:

```
SELECT comments.* FROM comments 
WHERE comments.comment = 'comment_id'
```

The final result is the summation of both these queries!

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: actually I've got an ID of article in a variable, I don't want to do the relation in query, I just want to get all the comments which belongs to current article id and also all the comments whose have subcomments ( comment column is filled by id of comment )

Comment: Provide some sample data to justify your question, else it is very tough to answer your question!

Comment: So I've got a table like this: https://imgur.com/a/q1rNL
I've got an ID of a article so I don't need to do the relations, what I want to do, is get first 2 comments which belong to article of an id of 33, and also comment with id of 4 which belongs to comment with id of 2.

Comment: I looked at your table, but where is the data linked at all - The article column value is `NULL` for the third row

Answer (score 0):

Use a union of two queries. One gets all the articles, the other gets the related comments:

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
WHERE article = :article
UNION ALL
SELECT c1.*
FROM comments AS c1
JOIN comments AS c2 ON c1.comment = c2.id
WHERE c2.article = :article
```